# jquery switch not changing css (3 colors)

Tags: jquery, css, background-color, classname

Do you see what I need to change in this code?

```
    <style>
    .bgColor1{background: red !important;}
    .bgColor2{background: blue !important;}
    .bgColor3{background: green !important;}
    </style>

    <button onclick="mySwitch()">SWITCH COLOR</button>
    <script>
    function mySwitch() {
       jQuery('.background').each(function(){
       var classes = ['bgColor1','bgColor2','bgColor3'];
       jQuery('.background').className = classes[($.inArray(jQuery('.background').className, classes)+1)%classes.length];
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Below works for only 2 colors toggleclass:

```
    <button onclick="jQuery('.background').toggleClass('bgColor2')">toggle bg</button>
```

But I guess a toggleClass is for ONLY 2 colors, not 3 :(

Comment: So explicitly `removeClass()` and `addClass()`.  `.className` off of a `jQuery` object isn't a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cycle through your classes using the modulo operator. I have produced a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gyb56kp1/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="background" class="bgColor0">
  <button id="but">SWITCH COLOR</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
let counter = 0;
$('#but').click(function () {

  $('#background').removeClass('bgColor' + ((counter % 3))); // Remove the previous color's class
  $('#background').addClass('bgColor' + ((counter + 1) % 3)); // Add the new colors class

  counter++;

});
```

CSS:

```
#background {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bgColor0{ background: red !important; }
.bgColor1{ background: blue !important; }
.bgColor2{ background: green !important; }
```